# Copy object via closure

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a copy of an object like this:

```
graphs = (function () {
    var trends = {
        pointSize: 10,
    };

    // Object Oriented JavaScript - pp 109
    var lockVariable = function(x) {
        return function() {
            return x;
        }
    };

    var getTrendsConfig = function() {
        return lockVariable(trends)();
    };
    return {
        getTrendsConfig : getTrendsConfig
    };
}());

c = graphs.getTrendsConfig();
c.pointSize = 11;
console.log(graphs.getTrendsConfig())
```

I was expecting to get printed a "{pointSize: 10}"

Because the *getTrendsConfig* function would pass the trends object to the *lockVariable* function, which would return the local value object: "{pointSize : 10}", instead I get "{pointSize: 11}".

I'm taking this from an example of the book "Object Oriented JavaScript" pp 108-109:

[image]

How do I get my expected result? Is it possible? And why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive values, such as numbers, in JavaScript, are immutable. You can copy `i` to `x` (as per the book), change `i` and leave `x` unchanged.

Objects are not immutable and are only ever addressed by reference. When you return the value of `trends` (`c = graphs.getTrendsConfig();`), you are returning a reference to the object (so `c` and `trends` both contain a reference to the same object). When you modify it, you modify that object. Getting another copy of `trends` gives you another copy of the reference… which still points to the same object.

The simple way to deal with this is to move the logic that creates the object inside the function that gets called.

```js
graphs = (function() {
  var lockVariable = function(x) {
    return function() {
      return x;
    }
  };

  var getTrendsConfig = function() {
    var trends = {
      pointSize: 10,
    };
    return lockVariable(trends)();
  };
  return {
    getTrendsConfig: getTrendsConfig
  };
}());

c = graphs.getTrendsConfig();
c.pointSize = 11;
console.log(graphs.getTrendsConfig())
```

Although you could simplify that to

```js
graphs = (function() {
  var getTrendsConfig = function() {
    return {
      pointSize: 10,
    };
  };
  return {
    getTrendsConfig: getTrendsConfig
  };
}());

c = graphs.getTrendsConfig();
c.pointSize = 11;
console.log(graphs.getTrendsConfig())
```

To go with something close to what your original code is trying to acheive, you could return an explicit copy of the object by using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
graphs = (function() {
  var trends = {
    pointSize: 10,
  };

  // Object Oriented JavaScript - pp 109
  var lockVariable = function(x) {
    return Object.assign({}, x);
  };

  var getTrendsConfig = function() {
    return lockVariable(trends);
  };
  return {
    getTrendsConfig: getTrendsConfig
  };
}());

c = graphs.getTrendsConfig();
c.pointSize = 11;
console.log(graphs.getTrendsConfig())
```

Comment: One question though, why moving the object inside the function that gets called, makes the code work?

Comment: @mclzc – When you call the function, you create the object. You don't reuse the same one.

Answer (score 1):

```js
graphs = (function () {
    var trends = {
        pointSize: 10,
    };

    // Object Oriented JavaScript - pp 109
    var lockVariable = function(x) {
        return function() {
            return x;
        }
    };

    var getTrendsConfig = function() {
        return lockVariable(trends)();
    };
    return {
        getTrendsConfig : getTrendsConfig
    };
}());

c = Object.assign({}, graphs.getTrendsConfig()); // same as ...graphs.getTrendsConfig() in ES6 spread syntax

c.pointSize = 11;

console.log(graphs.getTrendsConfig());
console.log("c =", c);
```

It's not producing your expected result because you re-assigned `c.pointSize` to `11` and that's why you're getting `11`;

In JavaScript, assigning an object to a variable is done by reference and not by value. This means that you're simply copying over the object's location in memory, causing any modification to affect the original value.

In your example when you assign `c = graphs.getTrendsConfig();`, `c` will now point to the same object's location/address.
When you did this `c.pointSize = 11`, you modified the same (original) object and not a copy.

**Solution:**
In other to make a copy of `graphs.getTrendsConfig()` you could use `Object.assign()` or the new ES6 spread syntax `...`. By making a copy you won't be modifying the original object's `pointSize` variable.

Comment: Thank you, your answer just was missing the core reason of why I was able to reassign pointSize  to 11.